# Why variable return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, scope

I've got little problem. I've got two method, index and create. When I try to check what's in randomUserId I see 'nill', but in View everything is correct.

```
  def index
    @randomUserId = rand(1..30)
  end

  def create
    puts "RANDOM: "
    puts @randomUserId

  end
```

Comment: How are you trying to check what's in `randomUserId`?  If you're creating a new instance, you'll need to call `index` first..

Comment: Is this a class? Are yout calling index before create?

Comment: You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails`, so I suppose you're in fact trying to create a controller, with `index` and `create` as actions. You don't seem to understand the basics of MVC, so I would suggest you to read some documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` [returns nil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) after it outputs a string, so the `create` methods returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

`create` and `index` are two very different methods. In a `Controller` they are not called together. You call only one or another. According to the code that you have supplied, you are only setting the value of `@randomUserId` in the `index` action.... not in the `create` action. You can't call a variable used in a different action - the value you set it to no longer exists, and will (correctly) return `nil`.

If you want the value of `@randomUserId` in the create action, you have to set it again in the `create` action, or pass it through the params somehow.

If the former, just copy the line that says `@randomUserId =rand(1..30)`.

If the latter, then you will need to tell us a lot more about what you are trying to do, your views etc, before we can help you.